# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease' : java.io.IOException - Proguard Issue

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, proguard, ioexception

Been struggling to figure the reason behind the issue (see stacktrace below) while trying to use proguard.

Apart from the libraries mentioned in gradle file, the app deals with opening `sockets`, `serializing/deserializing` data, `ciphers` and `jwt tokens`, dealing with `WifiManager` & `WifiP2pManager`.

It would be great if anyone could help point out the issue, or at least help me dig into the issue better. I have tried adding all the possible proguard rules for the different libraries and to not minify our own parent package as well.

**My gradle file**

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application' 

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

repositories {

    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }

}    

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    compile project(':android')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'

}

android {

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.some.org.package"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 5
        versionName "0.9.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}
```

**Proguard-rules.pro**

[Proguard file link](https://jsfiddle.net/shxkur9L/2)

**./gradlew clean assembleRelease -d --stacktrace**

https://jsfiddle.net/w7htgrxd/3

Answer (score 0):

The build log explicitly mentions the reasons why the build is failing. There are various references to missing classes, wrong configurations, attributes that are not kept although being used, ....

I suggest that you look at the referenced manual pages and apply the suggested changes, most of them being `-keepattributes ....`, `-dontwarn ...`.

If you do not manage to resolve all warnings, you can finally add also `-ignorewarnings` to ignore the remaining ones and let ProGuard continue processing your application.